# setjmp/longjmp in C#. Is it possible?

Tags: c#

I just ran into a problem when I need to do a goto into a local scope:

```
if(...)      
{
   DoSomethingHere();
   if (...) goto Label;
}
else if(...)
{
Label:
  DoSomethingHereToo();
}
```

, which apparently is not possible in C#.

Yes I know that using goto is considered a bad practice, but in this case it is much easier to do it with goto. So I'd rather not get into the whole "goto's are the source of all evil" discussion. For me a much more interesting and a more general question is the possibility of setjmp/longjmp in C#. So is it at all possible?

Comment: No. It isn't. So you'll have to describe what problem you're trying to solve, so we can try to suggest a better approach. If you try to write C code, then many things are seemingly easier with a goto. If you accept that you're not working in C, then your code can be rewritten to not use a goto, and be cleaner and more readable to boot. So take a step back and tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: jalf is right. I know you don't want to get into the goto's are evil discussion, but there is a reason why people don't like them; There are better flow control constructs. If you gave us more, maybe we can help.

Comment: Are you looking for how to do a `longjmp` or just a `goto`?

Comment: @Gabe. I'm interested in both.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why taking the body of the "else if" and extracting a method and then calling said method twice is such a bad thing?

Comment: I think that the implementation of yield keyword is similar to longjmp/setjmp. If it is possible to do yield, then why it isn't possible to do longjmp/setjmp?

Comment: @mlk Because extracting a method would require passing lots of parameters which are local variables. Of course I can wrap them inside a parameter object, but it would be much easier to do it with goto.

Comment: The implementation of iterator blocks is *absolutely nothing* like the implementation of setjmp/longjmp in C. The implementation of iterator blocks does, however, do *short* jumps that would otherwise be illegal in C#. Perhaps that's what you're thinking of?

Comment: @Max - I'd still see that as a much more readable solution.

Comment: @Eric Lippert. When the function with the iterator block is called the control flow is transferred from the inner function to the outer function and then back to the inner function again. The difference is that in C it is only possible to transfer control to the outer function, while the transfer from the outer to the inner is forbidden. I don't know how it is implemented internally, but at least it looks like it is making longjumps.

Comment: @Max: The iterator block is rewritten into a state machine that does short jump gotos to the line of code where the iterator is being resumed. See Raymond Chen's articles on how iterators work for details, or read the C# specification notes on possible iterator implementations.  See also my recent eleven part series on continuation passing style and async-await; it does a similar transformation.

Comment: "which apparently is not possible in C#." - just that it is possible :) @Max

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, I think you are confusing doing a "goto" into a local scope - a short jump - with a long jump - doing a goto to some place entirely outside of the current method. A classic C-style long jump can be thought of in two ways: one, it's like throwing an exception that does not clean up stack frames. Two, it is like returning from a function to the "wrong" address.

None of the above is possible in C#. C# does not support long jumps; we have try-catch-finally-throw to do non-local gotos in a clean, structured and safe way.

C# also does not support short jumps from outside a local variable declaration space to inside the space. The reason is because jumping into the middle of a block from outside is confusing, dangerous, hard to understand and hard to maintain.  The way this design goal was accomplished was by making *labels* have the same *scope* as local variables. The "goto" doesn't even see the label, any more than code in that location would see a local variable declared in a different local variable declaration space.

There are plenty of ways to solve your problem without using any goto statements at all. For example, the one that immediately comes to mind is

```
bool doFirstThing = false;
bool doSecondThing = false;
if (firstCondition) 
{
    doFirstThing = true;
    doSecondThing = true;
}
else if (secondCondition)
{
    doSecondThing = true;
}
if (doFirstThing) 
{
    DoFirstThing();
}
if (doSecondThing)
{
    DoSecondThing();
}
```

That's perfectly straightforward, easy to read, easy to debug, and so on.

Alternatively: if the shared code in the "doSecondThing" consequence is actually difficult to refactor into a method of its own then consider taking a step back and deciding whether your control flow is simply too complicated to begin with. For example, if you are mutating lots of variables in a loop then perhaps there is some technique you can use to simplify that situation and do fewer mutations. Can you give more information about what this code is doing and why it is difficult to refactor it?

Comment: The code converts a very poorly designed database. The problem is that the source database is designed in such a way that the same table can contain records of different type, but there is no flag that designates the type. Also order of records is significant. For instance the record is interpreted differently if there are different records prepending it. Basically the conversion code looks more like a state machine.

Comment: It's just a matter of preference I guess. To me it is easier to read and maintain the code with 3 ifs and 1 goto, rather that the code with 4 ifs and two additional flags. And in my case there are many more ifs and flags in this procedure.

Comment: @Max: It sounds like your code is very complicated; I would consider taking a step back and seeing if there is some larger refactoring you could perform that would make the logic easier to follow. For example, if you really do need a state machine then you could simplify your code by writing a library that allows you to more easily define state machines, and then define your control flow by constructing the appropriate state machine out of your library.

Answer (score 5):

**Here be dragons.**

Trying to answer the question in the title, my first attempt to accomplish it was, naturally, via interop and importing *setjmp* and *longjmp* from msvcrt.dll.

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="_setjmp")]
static extern int setjmp(out Jmp_buf env);

[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void longjmp(ref Jmp_buf env, int val);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Size=16*4)]
struct Jmp_buf{}
```

It appears I've made the import signatures correct but ultimately, it cannot work this way. P/Invoke creates a wrapper around the call to native setjmp, thus the stack frame of `setjmp` is already released when the P/Invoke method returns. It's no surprise `longjmp` throws *AccessViolationException* then.

That's it. There's **no way** into the mounta... I mean, in pure C# to call these two functions. The absolutely only way I can think of is to "inline" the call via hacking the JITted native code of some method and manually include the call to *setjmp*. Sorry, even I see no reason to try to do that without any serious justification.

But if I can't call the function from C#, I surely can from C++/CLI!

```
#include <csetjmp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace std;

typedef void (*UnmanagedHandler)(int code);

void mysetjmp(jmp_buf env, UnmanagedHandler handler)
{
    handler(setjmp(env));
    throw 0;
}

void mylongjmp(jmp_buf env, int val)
{
    longjmp(env, val);
}

namespace jmptestdll
{
    public delegate void JumpHandler(int code);

    public ref class JumpBuffer
    {
    private:
        jmp_buf *env;

    public:
        JumpBuffer()
        {
            env = new jmp_buf[1];
        }

        ~JumpBuffer()
        {
            this->!JumpBuffer();
        }

        void Set(JumpHandler^ handler)
        {
            if(env)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(handler);
                UnmanagedHandler act = static_cast<UnmanagedHandler>(ptr.ToPointer());
                try{
                    mysetjmp(*env, act);
                }catch(int code)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        void Jump(int value)
        {
            if(env)
            {
                mylongjmp(*env, value);
            }
        }

    protected:
        !JumpBuffer()
        {
            if(env)
            {
                delete[] env;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I've probably made some horrid mistakes in that code, but C++ is not my native language, sorry. It does the trick, though. For some reason, returning from `mysetjmp` throws *AccessViolationException* as well but I haven't found the reason. "Returning" via `throw` works.

```
var env = new JumpBuffer();
env.Set(
    delegate(int code)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(code);
        env.Jump(code+1);
        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye world!");
    }
);
```

"Goodbye world!" is never shown, and instead it displays numbers from 0 ascending. Porting the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h#Simple_example) also works:

```
static JumpBuffer buf = new JumpBuffer();

static void second()
{
    Console.WriteLine("second");
    try{
        buf.Jump(1);
    }finally{
        Console.WriteLine("finally");
    }
}

static void first()
{
    second();
    Console.WriteLine("first");
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    buf.Set(
        val => {
            Console.WriteLine(val);
            if(val == 0) first();
            else Console.WriteLine("main");
        }
    );

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Output:

> 0
>   second
>   finally
>   1
>   main

At first I thought it would also skip the `finally` handler, but I guess it's not that much evil. The only downside is that we cannot write code directly after `Set` and have to pass a handler instead.

If you want to jump into an arbitrary method to an arbitrary label, make a state machine.

Hmm, there are internal state machines in C# supporting iterators and `async`. Iterators are too limited for our purposes, but with `await`, it may be precisely what we need.

```
public class LongJump
{
    Continuation continuation;

    public SetAwaiter Set()
    {
        return new SetAwaiter(this);
    }

    public JumpAwaiter Jump()
    {
        return new JumpAwaiter(this);
    }

    public struct JumpAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        readonly LongJump jump;

        public JumpAwaiter(LongJump jump)
        {
            this.jump = jump;
        }

        public JumpAwaiter GetAwaiter()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public bool IsCompleted{
            get{
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void OnCompleted(Action callerContinuation)
        {
            jump.continuation.Continue();
        }

        public void GetResult()
        {

        }
    }

    public struct SetAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        readonly LongJump jump;

        public SetAwaiter(LongJump jump)
        {
            this.jump = jump;
        }

        public SetAwaiter GetAwaiter()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public bool IsCompleted{
            get{
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void OnCompleted(Action callerContinuation)
        {
            jump.continuation = new Continuation(callerContinuation);
            callerContinuation();
        }

        public void GetResult()
        {

        }
    }

    private class Continuation
    {
        private readonly int savedState;
        private readonly object stateMachine;
        private readonly FieldInfo field;
        private readonly Action action;

        internal Continuation(Action action)
        {
            stateMachine = action.Target.GetType().InvokeMember("m_stateMachine", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField, null, action.Target, null);
            field = stateMachine.GetType().GetField("<>1__state", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            savedState = (int)field.GetValue(stateMachine);
            this.action = action;
        }

        internal void Continue()
        {
            field.SetValue(stateMachine, savedState);
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

public static async Task MainAsync()
{
    var jump = new LongJump();
    Console.WriteLine("Begin");
    int code = 0;
    await jump.Set();
    Console.WriteLine(code);
    code += 1;
    await InnerMethod(code, jump);
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}

public static async Task InnerMethod(int code, LongJump jump)
{
    if(code < 5)
    {
        await jump.Jump();
    }
}
```

I got a little inspiration from Jon Skeet's awesome [article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/11/11/eduasync-part-15-implementing-comefrom-with-a-horrible-hack/) on implementing COMEFROM in C#.

To sum up this code, calling `await jump.Set();` actually remembers the state of the state machine at that moment, and then continues with the execution as usual. `await jump.Jump();` discards any continuation after that line, and resumes the old continuation. You can even jump into a method which has already ended, but don't return from it then, because it would try to mark its task completed again, resulting in an exception.

I guess it's also possible to combine the async approach with the C++/CLI code, to remove `await` from `jump.Jump()`, but that's not too useful.

Remember that there is also already a useful "long jump" mechanism in C# - exception handling.

Answer (score 3):

## Do not do any of the stuff described below.  It is a bad idea, and is intended only for informational purposes or as an intellectual exercise.

The C# language does not support jumping outside of scope.  So, it is impossible to do what you are asking in C#.  However, **IL** will allow you to do this, because IL is lower level than C# and does not really have this form of scope.

So, if you really want to support goto while ignoring scope, you could fake it using a post-compiler tool to tweak the IL.  Something similar to [Mike Stall's tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/tool-to-allow-inline-il-in-c-vb-net) .  Note: **This is a horrible, horrible idea.**  I should feel shame for even contemplating this as an intellectual exercise.

Reasons this will break if you actually try to do it for production code:

- The C# compiler will be oblivious to your special code, so it might rearrange your code in "safe" ways that do not take your non-local goto into account.
- Writing a C# compiler is hard.  Creating a post-processor to embed random IL into your code is not overly difficult (especially with Mike Stall's tool as a starting point), but doing it in a reliable way is very difficult.
- C# doesn't support non-local goto for a reason; it's really easy to write broken code when you use non-local goto.  Even worse if you do an end-run around the C# compiler and try to force it working yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't:

```
condition1Cache = condition1;
condition2Cache = false;
if ( condition1Cache )
{    
   yadda yadda
   condition2Cache = condition2;
}
/* short-circuit evaluation will prevent condition3 from being evaluated (and possibly having side-effects) in a manner compatible with the original code. */
if ( ( condition1Cache && condition2Cache ) || (!condition1Cache && condition3) ) 
{
   bada bing
}
```

work?

Edit:  Updated to use caching to avoid possibility of conditions causing side-effects when you don't want them to.

Comment: `condition1` is evaluated twice, which could have side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

If the conditions and the resulting code can be expressed as rvalues, you may be able to use the short-circuit operations to do things that would otherwise not be possible without using gotos or flags.  In your case:

```
if (condition1() ? (DoSomethingHere(),condition2()) : condition3())
  DoSomethingHere2();
```

Probably not how I would generally code it, unless DoSomethingHere was clearly tied in with the evaluation of condition2, but it should yield the desired semantics.  I'm not sure I'd expect a compiler to recognize the effect of ?: on the condition (as distinct from evaluating it as a zero/non-zero result and and doing a conditional jump based on that).

BTW, I tend to hate certain uses of flags more than I hate gotos, since each flag adds another 'dimension' to program flow--if one is doing a graph of program flow, every different combination of flags that may be relevant at any given spot in the program represents a different node.  If the necessary execution pattern can be achieved with a 'goto' and no flags, that may well be preferable to a flag and no 'goto'.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the following is equivalent:

```
if(condition1)      
{
   DoSomethingHere();
}

if(condition2)
{
   DoSomethingHereToo();
}
```

Can you supply more context to show why this would not work?

Comment: In his case, there are three conditions, all of which are evaluated at most once. I don't think you can do the same without using some temporary Boolean variables.

Comment: @Dialecticus: Yes, it was an else if, but a goto into that else if makes the else no longer make sense. Perhaps condition2 needs to be changed to make the logic make sense, but that is why I asked for more context.

Comment: @Heinzi: you are correct; I think @Eric does a nice job of summing up how it should look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way, I am not sure if it is the best, to do what you want to do with without goto's

```
bool doSomthingElseFlag = false
if(...)      
{
   DoSomethingHere();
   if (...)
      doSomthingElseFlag = true;
}
else if(...)
{
  DoSomethingHere2();
  if (...)
     doSomthingElseFlag = true;
}
else if(...)
{
  //Not This function does not need the other function to run
  //so we do not set the flag
  DoSomethingHere3();
}
if (doSomthingElseFlag)
{
  DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the topic of setjmp/longjmp, you can use it's bigger brother: [continuations](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/~duchier/python/continuations.html). C# doesn't support them within the language, but you can use [continuation passing style](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2010/03/19/functional-c-continuation-passing-style/), combined with [lazy evaluation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43234/Csharp-A-Method-for-Tail-Call-Recursion.aspx) or [trampolines](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/04/bouncing-on-your-tail.html) so you don't get a [image: stack overflow].

Answer (score 0):

This problem cannot be solved with setjmp/longjmp.

With longjmp you can only jump backwards *in time* to a location where you have been before and where the processor state was saved by a previous setjmp, so that it can be restored.

So essentially you *return* to a location where setjmp was called before.
You cannot jump to an arbitrary location. With longjmp *could* also jump back in time to a subroutine where the context is already destroyed, but in this case you get crash or malfunction, so you should not do this.

Jumping into blocks generally is not possible in no modern languages.
Even longjmp does not do this, essentially it unrolls the stack and essentially *returns* into a block.
If this where possible you could jump over variable declarations and initializations and this can give evil bugs. Only jump out of blocks, this is usually secure.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible. Consider this :

```
   void method1()
    {
       for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
       {
           method2(i);
           Console.WriteLine(i);

            EndOfLoop: //This is something like a setjmp marker
                    ;
         }
    }

    void method2(int i)
    {
       if (i%10 == 0)
           Console.WriteLine("Next Number can be divided by 10");

   // Now Long jmp to EndOfLoop
    #if IL
        br EndOfLoop 
    #endif
    }
```

However, it can soon make your code unreadable :)

The output of the code would be:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Next Number can be divided by 10 10 11..... Each in a new line.

ILDASM output for Method 1:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  method1() cil managed
{
  // Code size       35 (0x23)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 i,
           [1] bool CS$4$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  br.s       IL_0019
  IL_0005:  nop
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  call       void Test::method2(int32)
  IL_000c:  nop
  IL_000d:  ldloc.0
  IL_000e:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_0013:  nop
  IL_0014:  nop
  IL_0015:  ldloc.0
  IL_0016:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0017:  add
  IL_0018:  stloc.0
  IL_0019:  ldloc.0
  IL_001a:  ldc.i4.s   100
  IL_001c:  clt
  IL_001e:  stloc.1
  IL_001f:  ldloc.1
  IL_0020:  brtrue.s   IL_0005
  IL_0022:  ret
} // end of method Test::method1
```

ILDASM Output for Method 2:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  method2(int32 i) cil managed
{
  // Code size       27 (0x1b)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] bool CS$4$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s   10
  IL_0004:  rem
  IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0006:  ceq
  IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0009:  ceq
  IL_000b:  stloc.0
  IL_000c:  ldloc.0
  IL_000d:  brtrue.s   IL_001a
  IL_000f:  ldstr      "Next Number can be divided by 10"
  IL_0014:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0019:  nop
  IL_001a:  ret
} // end of method Test::method2
```

Sample Output of Execution :

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it would compile? I haven't tried the inline IL tool, but I've reconstructed the appropriate CIL and got "Unable to find forward reference label 'EndOfLoop'". By the way, `br` takes a relative offset to the label, and that makes no sense outside of the method instruction scope.

Comment: Hi, I tried it before posting here and it worked. Probably you could give it a shot by creating a new project in VS...

Comment: I've tried to compile it now, and it gives the same error - "Unable to find forward reference label". Could you please post the CIL disassembly of the program?

Comment: @IllidanS4 : There was a mistake in the code (method2() signature). It is corrected now. public class Program{ public static void Main(string[] args){method1();} //Paste the rest of code here } ... This should work.

Comment: I've already corrected the mistake myself. Please, post the output of ILDASM for the program, if it works for you.

Comment: I see. It prints "Next Number can be divided by 10", then numbers from 0 to 9, and repeats, 10 to 19 and so on. However, based on your original program's supposed logic, it shouldn't print any number at all, because `br EndOfLoop` would jump right to the label, skipping the `WriteLine` above it. As you can see from the dissasembly of the second method, `br EndOfLoop` isn't compiled at all and the method simply returns.

Comment: IllidanS4: Just that it will not.. The jump to EndOfLoop does not return until the for - condition exits. There is a branch to   IL_001a: in method 1 - from Method 2... Please have a look at "brtrue.s   IL_001a"

Comment: Well, that is branching to the end of the method, not outside of it. The `ret` instruction does the act of actual leaving the method, and it jumps to the point where it was called. And the branch you mention corresponds to the `if` above, not to the `br EndOfLoop` instruction, which is completely ignored, as I have stated before.

Comment: @IllidanS4 : It branches to 001a at method 1... And at 0020 (method 1) - there is yet another conditional branching to 0005 - which forms the body of the 'for' loop...  The 'rem' performs the i%10 operation. brtrue.s executes when the result of operation is i%10 is non-zero. It "jumps" to IL_001a - which is still within the body of the 'for' loop.... And the loop continues. In case the result of 'i%10' is a zero, method2 returns... Which again sets the virtual Ins. pointer effectively to 000d in method 1. The code was tested and it worked. The br "EndOfLoop" is not ignored.

Comment: Through this lengthy discussion, I've completely forgot the point of it. There is still no evidence of `br` performing a jump between methods. Were the `#if IL` segment removed, it would still do the same thing, and it actually does it, as in normal C# compiller, the following block is ignored when `IL ` is not defined. If `br EndOfLoop` did something, at least one number would be skipped in the out, which it isn't. Heck, the `br` is not even in your IL code.
 
I am just repeating myself now...

Comment: Am not sure as to why there is a downrate... @IllidanS4 one suggestion is - do not trust your instincts... Copy the code - put it in your VS and execute it... See for yourself...

Comment: I have executed it thrice by now, with and without the `#if IL`... segment. Same results still. If you want to prove that the `br` there has some impact on the execution, find a different example.

Comment: You're using the InlineIL hack, which is no vanilla c#.