# Is there a way to access a label from another function? C#

Tags: c#, function, goto

I've been trying to make a function with a goto, and the label for the goto is outside of the method. I can't add the label to the function and making the label public breaks everything. is Is there a way to fix it?

The code I'm putting is very small because its just a demo of what I want to happen:

```
public static void Main(string[] arg)
{
     start:
}
public static void ToStart()
{
    goto start;
}
```

Comment: Hi ze soup, please have a look at the article [ask]. The community asks that you do some research before asking questions here. A couple things you could have done before posting is 1) Try it (always a great way to learn) and 2) Search for the C# language reference or articles about goto in C#. It's likely a question such as this could be closed by moderators.

Comment: It is almost always a bad idea to use `goto` for anything. It breaks the flow of the current code making it hard to reason that it is correct.

Comment: Im sorry that this was a bad question. This is my first post on stack overflow after i decided to make an account. Ill make sure to read the link you gave me. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setjmp/longjmp in C#. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185594/setjmp-longjmp-in-c-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do that. Please take a look at the [Goto Statement in the C# Language Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-goto-statement).

> The target of a goto identifier statement is the labeled statement with the given label. If a label with the given name does not exist in the current function member, or if the goto statement is not within the scope of the label, a compile-time error occurs.

You've gotten some suggestions in comments and other answers.

Within a method you want to primarily rely on structured flow control `if`, `while`, `for`, `switch`, etc. Use `goto` rarely, but there are use cases where it can come in handy. But usually not the first thing you want to try.

To break up code into logical units you should use methods (as you have started to do). Rather than using `goto` to pass control to another method you "call the method". Methods have a large benefit over goto in that they allow you to pass arguments and return values back to the calling code. And example call: `double z = Math.Max(x,y);` where I call the `Max` method which takes two numeric arguments and returns the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you can do a `goto` to a different method. I would then be able to write this fictional piece of code:

```
public static void ToStart()
{
    goto start;
}

public static void DoStuff(int number, string text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
    start:
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

The presumption would be that if I called `ToStart` it would `goto` directly in to the middle of `DoStuff` and proceed to call `Console.WriteLine(text);` - but what would the value of `text` be? It was never set. That could, and probably would, be bad.

Let re-write this with valid C# code and see how it should be handled.

```
public static void ToStart()
{
    DoStuffPartB("From ToStart");
}

public static void DoStuff(int number, string text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
    DoStuffPartB(text);
}

public static void DoStuffPartB(string text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

This code works just fine.

The bottom-line is that if you are using `goto` you probably are doing something wrong. There's (almost) always a way to avoid it.

The question is what's in your `Main` after the `start:` label? Then we could suggest a proper rewrite.

Answer (score -1):

Why not using a function?

goto: is rarely used, maybe for nested loops, or nested if's